# C++ shared_ptr return this from derived method

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

I have been using this:

```
struct Bar;

struct Foo 
{
   virtual Bar * GetBar() { return nullptr; }
}

struct Bar : public Foo
{
   virtual Bar * GetBar() { return this; }
}

Foo * b = new Bar();
//...
b->GetBar();
```

I used this instead of slow `dynamic_cast`. Now I have changed my code to use `std::shared_ptr`

```
std::shared_ptr<Foo> b = std::shared_ptr<Bar>(new Bar());
```

How can I change `GetBar` method to return `std::shared_ptr` and get the same functionality as with raw pointers (no need for dynamic_cast) ?

I have tried this:

```
 struct Foo : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Foo>
 {
     virtual std::shared_ptr<Bar> GetBar() { return nullptr; }
 } 


struct Bar : public Foo
{
    virtual std::shared_ptr<Bar> GetBar() { return shared_from_this(); }
}
```

But it wont compile

Comment: Surely `GetBar` should not be returning `Bar *` - but `Foo *`

Comment: @EdHeal That would defeat the purpose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::enable_shared_from_this<Foo>::shared_from_this()` returns a `shared_ptr<Foo>`. So you need an explicit pointer downcast.

```
virtual std::shared_ptr<Bar> GetBar() {
    return std::static_pointer_cast<Bar>(shared_from_this());
}
```